# python3 - if loop for bubblesort algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, loops, if-statement

So I'm having a little trouble with my code and i'm 99% sure it's my 'if/elif' loop. I have the txt files imported and my bubblesort algorithm working but whatever the input it will only print 'array1' of 3.

```
    examplearray=(input('Select Array'))
    if examplearray == 'ex1' or 'ex1'.upper():
        bubbleSort(ex1array)
        print(ex1array)
    elif examplearray == 'ex2' or 'ex2'.upper():
        bubbleSort(ex2array)
        print(ex2array)
    elif examplearray == 'ex3' or 'ex3'.upper():
        bubbleSort(ex3array)
        print(ex3array)
```

anyone have any pointers for this please? just ask if you need anymore of my code; thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you botched your condition statement. What you meant was `if A == (B or C)` but you can't do that, you have ti write `if (A==B) or (A==C)`

Comment: i shouted at myself for not seeing this, thank you so much lmao A+++++